# Multi-repo vs Monorepo and nested monorepos

Tags: monorepo

I'm currently in the position at my current workplace to improve our project setup. We have multiple projects/products, whereas some of those have dependencies to each others, while others don't.

Some of the projects are bigger than others, one of which is so big, that it is already a monorepo. The other projects consist of between 2 to roughly 30 files.

My idea was to create a monorepo with all the projects (let's call them "A", "B", "C", "D") inside. But I see multiple problems with this approach:

- Some Employees only have to work on project "A", while others have to only work on "D". In a monorepo approach, they all would work on the same git repository, and could theoretically modify code in projects they shouldn't be working on.
- As I said, one of the projects (let's say "D") is already a monorepo. I'd have to nest monorepos or change the project structure of "D".

The multi-repo approach has the big downside, that I have to republish any project's package each time it get's changed, which increases the overhead in terms of publishing and installing dependencies.

Comment: While the considerations are legit and valuable, there's not really a specific question in here. If you just need people to share their experiences with similar situations, there are better places than SO for that. Otherwise, try asking a specific question to which the answer will help you make your decision.

Answer (score 0):

Check this blog post:
https://medium.com/outbrain-engineering/mono-repo-vs-multi-repo-vs-hybrid-whats-the-right-approach-5436c575c6e0

Its talking about our experience at Outbrain with those approaches.

Summarizing the problems in both mono/multi repos and talking about hybrid approach.
The hybrid approach is talking that combination of mono and multi repo might be also a solution and it depends on the use case.

Mono-Repo - Good to run fast and have centralized place to define dependencies but bad when project starts to scale up.

Multi-repo - Gives full autonomy to all teams but very hard to track and follow all changes and update dependencies among repos.

Comment: According to your comment, I updated and added more content .
I really think the blog post may help people to understand better and learn from our experience .

Comment: Flag retracted but I am sorry, that's not a downvote of mine.